# Reproducing BingPreview JavaScript errors

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, bing, bots

I have a website that gets visits from BingPreview/1.0b*, which is likely a bot for Bing.

I'm getting an error that looks like it can't find a DOM Element that I'm pretty sure should exist. I'm not getting errors from any other browsers (tested in all major browsers) or bots (although lack of errors doesn't necessarily prove anything).

My most likely explanation is that it's executing JavaScript before the document has been fully loaded but I don't know how to reproduce a BingPreview bot visit.

**How do I reproduce BingPreview visits / JavaScript errors?**

* Full UA-string is: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534+ (KHTML, like Gecko) BingPreview/1.0b`

Notes: The visit occured 3 days ago, everything I can find about BingPreview seems that it's not publicly available anymore (dead links and such)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, The user agent is, as you presumed, some sort of Bot for Bing. There have been questions like [this one](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27498/bingpreview-user-agent) which suggest that Microsoft have been testing some sort of Page Preview for their search results, similar to google's.

Because it is them testing and their implementation of the bot (the bot's javascript engine) that most likely caused errors, there's also most likely no way for you to reproduce it.

What you can surely do is set your User agent string in Chrome [in the dev console](http://googlesystem.blogspot.ch/2011/12/changing-user-agent-new-google-chrome.html) to the Bing Bot UA and see if something happens, because then you have the same user agent and, as it looks from the UA, the same engine (Webkit). Bot most likely, nothing will happen, because if something is wrong there, it is them doing undisclosed testing on your site.

**EDIT**

There's also [this post](http://www.webmasterworld.com/search_engine_spiders/4410107.htm) on webmasterworld, suggesting that is actually some sort of preview feature, which has also been seen on the bing results pages, but in random manner. I cannot confirm it, Bing for me looks the same as always, without previews.

**SECOND EDIT**

And Microsoft themselves do not seem [too keen on replying](http://www.bing.com/community/webmaster/f/12248/p/675468/9680051.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. I tried switching the UserAgent string in Chrome but that had no effect.

Comment: Do you have any inline javascript or javascript relying on css properties (for example, do you select this element only when it's visible?). The only thing I can imagine is either the bing bot only executing unobstrusive javascript or having problems with the viewport. You can try to change that. Apart from that, I cannot imagine how to reproduce the visit.

Comment: I also tried running IE9 with the BingPreview UA-string but that doesn't give any problems. IE7 and IE8 just break. I wanted to try IE10 but it's locked to Win8 currently. - The error I'm getting looks like it can't find a DOM Element, I don't know which one since I don't get a proper stack trace, but all of them should always be there (ie. it works in all other browsers). Thanks for your effort but I'm still stuck.

Comment: The exact error is that `document.getElementById("XYZ")` returns `null` which is checked against in my framework.

Comment: Looks like there's nothing you can do about that, this may be due to how the Bing Preview Bot scraps the page / executes the javascript on it. Unless you're inserting the element you're trying to get asynchronously at an earlier stage (which may not be done by the bot). But if it's in the original html delivered by the server, there's no way to figure that out, mainly because there are no reliable informations on the rendering engine, scraping technique, and javascript execution of the bot.

Comment: I'm also experiencing lots of JavaScript errors on my site generated by BingPreview/1.0b. I searched around and found that Bing's Page Snapshots were [announced](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/10/26/page-snapshots-in-bing-windows-8-app-to-bring-new-crawl-traffic-to-sites/) in late 2012. The user agent is also [documented](https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/which-crawlers-does-bing-use-8c184ec0). Accessing a tour page tells me the feature is not available in my region (Germany).